# using Natural order with treeset in java

Tags: java

I am getting an unexpected output for this. Please have a look. I am not able to find the problem. What's wrong with my program?  Can anybody explain? I am getting the output

```
    Joe     Sue     Mike      Clare   Juliet       
    Joe         Mike        Clare        Juliet
```

objects in `TreeSets` and `TreeMaps` and with `Collections.sort()` for `Lists`, using the `Comparable` Interface.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        int len1 = name.length();
        int len2 = person.name.length();

        if(len1 > len2) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(len1 < len2) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        SortedSet<Person> set = new TreeSet<Person>();


//adding  Element
        addElements(list);
        addElements(set);


//sorting element 
        Collections.sort(list);

//displaying result 
        showElements(list);
        System.out.println();
        showElements(set);
    }


//adding element methods

    private static void addElements(Collection<Person> col) {
        col.add(new Person("Joe"));
        col.add(new Person("Sue"));
        col.add(new Person("Juliet"));
        col.add(new Person("Clare"));
        col.add(new Person("Mike"));
    }

    private static void showElements(Collection<Person> col) {
        for(Person element: col) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Joe     Sue     Mike      Clare   Juliet       
Joe     sue    Mike        Clare        Juliet

Comment: @RohitJain look at the code. `TreeSet` is supposed to add the data sorted and `Collections#sort(list)` should sort the elements in `ArrayList`, then OP print both collections and give different results.

Comment: @RohitJain Joe     Sue     Mike      Clare   Juliet       
    Joe         Mike        Clare        Juliet

Comment: @sanjaybrandtest1 But you are comparing your Person objects using their lengths name. Since Joe and Sue have the same length for their name, Sue is not added to the set.

Comment: Please take more time to format your post in future - your entire code was indented 12 spaces, making it very hard to read. Look at the preview before you hit submit.

Comment: i am using tree so out put is missiong >>> 'sue' as i mention.

Comment: @sanjaybrandtest1: I don't know what you mean by "i am not tree" but you're definitely using a `TreeSet`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are comparing the persons by the *length* of their names. And the names "Joe" and "Sue" have the same length. So only one of them can occur in the TreeSet. However, this comparison criterion is *not consistent with the implementation of* `equals`!

You should place your `Person` objects into a list, and sort this list with `Collections#sort` - preferably, with an own `Comparator`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659849

EDIT: Further explaination:

A `Set` can contain each element only *once*. And by the way that you specified your `compareTo` method, you impled that "Sue" and "Joe" are equal (because their names have equal lengths). So they can not both appear in a `Set`.

Note: They are not really equal, based on the `equals` method. But the `TreeSet` uses the `compareTo` method, and this `compareTo` method is currently not consistent with `equals`. So the `Set` shows a wrong behavior because of your wrong `compareTo` method.

EDIT: A possible solution:

If the names have equal lengths, you can compare them alphabetically. This way, the `compareTo` method becomes *consistent with equals*: It will return 0 if and only if the names are equal.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person person) {
    int len1 = name.length();
    int len2 = person.name.length();

    if(len1 > len2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(len1 < len2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return name.compareTo(person.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: @sanjaybrandtest1 Is the explaination from Meno Hochschild in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22256605 sufficient?

Comment: @sanjaybrandtest1 I added a possible solution in the answer

Answer (score 1):

A `SortedSet` uses compareTo for evaluation if an element can be added to the Set. Your input contains two names with same length (your comparison criterion), hence one of Joe or Sue must be filtered out (in your case Sue).

Comment: @sanjaybrandtest1 Marco13 has already posted a fine answer (was a few seconds quicker). In order to ensure to get all names into your Set you have to change your comparison criterion to get unique names in the context of your compareTo()-method. So just using length is not sufficient. You might compare lexicographically the strings in case of equal lengths in order to return non-zero comparison result.

Answer (score 0):

The TreeSet documentation talks about having(not mandatory) compareTo implementaion consistent with equals. In your case 'Joe' and 'Sue' are of equal length and as per your compareTo implementation they are same. One workaround would be  to compare the hashcode values in compareTo methods if they are of equal length.