# java.lang.ClassCastException: List cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I need to add two lists of objects of the same type to a SET. I should make sure the order of the set is of **natural order** and there is **no reparation** in the SET.

I read answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256445/using-natural-order-with-treeset-in-java) but it did not help.

For example my inputs and output should be as following

List 1

```
A A1 List1
B B1 List1
B B1 List1
```

List 2

```
C C1 List2
D D1 List2
A A1 List2
```

Output

```
List1
A A1
B B1
List2
C C1
D D1
```

As you can see the second `B B1` does not exist in `List 1` of the output because there are two `B B1` on the `list 1`.

Also `A A1` does not exist in the `list 2` of output because it already exists in `List 1` of the output.

Also the order of each list is kept. (List 1 is added first so List 1 is on top of the list, after that List 2 and the order of all of their elements is preserved.)

```
public class MyList{
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String group;

    //setters and getters
}

List<MyList> list1 = new ArrayList<MyList>();
List<MyList> list2 = new ArrayList<MyList>();
....
Set<MyList> output = new TreeSet<MyList>();
output.addAll(list1);
output.addAll(list2);
```

Exception that is thrown

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myproject.MyList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
```

To solve the issue I added Comparable to MyList class, but it changes the order of the SET. How to keep the natural order of the SET?

Comment: What do you mean by natural order?

Comment: @Codebender I mean the order that they were added to the set. Please have a look at my sample output list in the question.

Comment: Ok so the data structure you have provided above is not a list...not sure why you keep calling it a list. Provide the full implementation of the "list" that shows how you add things to it

Comment: @Smac89 they are both ArrayLists, question is updated.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a `Set` that maintains insertion order, the class you're looking for is [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

The implementation is a hashtable that also maintains a linked list of entries, which allows you to iterate over the entries in the order they were added.

Comment: is that the best option in terms of performance?

Comment: @Jack: `LinkedHashSet` has amortized O(1) insertion and lookup, and iteration is O(N). Asymptotically you aren't going to get better than that. However, the constant factors are going to be slightly higher than `ArrayList` or `HashSet`, and the memory usage will be a handful of bytes more per entry. In short: it's highly unlikely that it will make your program slow. As always, when dealing with performance issues, *measure* rather than guessing. You're much more likely to find performance problems in your own code (e.g. in your `equals` and `hashCode`) than in standard library code.

Answer (score 1):

"The natural order" of the **TreeSet** is implementing by **compareTo()** in your MyList.class. Because TreeSet don't know how to order your objects, but its need to do this necessarily.
If you need ordering by "that they were added to the set" - use **LinkedHashSet**.

Comment: `HashSet` will never guarantee you the order.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Use **LinkedHashSet**. It preserves order based on insertion order.

Comment: @AlexeyKhamitov is that the best option in terms of performance?

Comment: @Jack if you really need Set - yes, it is.                  
LinkedHashSet / TreeSet:
add O(1) / O(log n)
get O(1) / O(log n)
contains O(1) / O(log n)
remove O(1) / O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

Create equals and hashcode on name and code only.  You can  also make a compare method that maintains the original order.

Answer (score 0):

> How to keep the natural order of the SET?

`List` is made for this , not `set`, Set is not ordered, but TreeSet is only when you define `Comparator` to sorted according to the specified comparator. otherwise TreeSet does not know in which order it should save the objects.

Take a List it will give you the required output.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use TreeSet then you must definitely use Compartor or Comparable to extend your class mylist a hashset will not guarantee order and any object which need to be ordered/sort in some way other than primitive/wrapper type need explicit way to tell JVM how to sort them otherwise JVM will not know on which property it has to sort in object hence the error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myproject.MyList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable